# I have a question about the power node

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, shader-nodes

[image]
when connected like this,
[image]
I understand that based on the origin, negative and positive values are assigned.
[image]
I connected the power node like that and set the exponent value to 5.
[image]
I got this result. Why does this part turn black? Shouldn't it not turn black since raising a positive number to the power of 5 is positive?
I also noticed that when adjusting the values very slightly, the result can suddenly change drastically. Is it because I'm not understanding it correctly, or is the power node not perfect?

Comment: i think it is not really black, but very near to black, since it is a very low number near zero. You may wanna prove that with a multiply node afterwards where it should get lighter. It couldn't get lighter if it would be zero (what you are assuming) As you know, numbers lower than 1 with power bigger than 1 are getting lower.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thank you so much for answering my questions.